# phonegap javascript alert not working?

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I am trying to build a very simple android application using phonegap along with eclipse.I am very new to phonegap . When i run the application the page gets displayed in the emulator but my javascript alert function is not working.Can someone please help me ?? Here is my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);


function onDeviceReady()
{
alert('hello');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Hello Phonegap!!</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: alert("hello"); try change this

Comment: tried . But it did not work .

Comment: Any error you get in console? Are you able to view the page fine in Ripple emulator in Chrome? This is my issue too when I first started and fixed it.

Comment: I would try it without the script tags that are referencing jquery and jqm first.  Does that help?  If so I would then try again with those scripts local.

Comment: I dnt gt any sch error but when i tried calling alert function through <body onload="abc()"> and then writing alert in abc function it worked..dont know what is the problem with document.addEventListener()

Comment: I am getting two errors. One is plugin.xml missing - don't know why does it need plugin.xml when i have already included xml/config.xml in res folder.Another error is unable to open asset URL : file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js

Answer (score 2):

Add this phonegap version tag in your html page.

```
<script src="cordova-x.x.x.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Without this, phonegap events will not work on your page.

Comment: I believe the new version has version number removed in js file.

Comment: I have done that in my code.Bt still i am facing problems.                                                                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>